# Shell Script Overwrite a Column After Cut

Tags: bash, shell

I have a csv file that I alter some of its columns after using cut command.

```
123;bbb ;10.01.2010
456;ddd;11.01.2015
789;aaa;20.12.2010
222;ccc;15.10.2010
```

As an example, I get the second column, trim and sort it on the code below;

```
cut -f 2 -d ';' data.csv | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | sort
```

How can i overwrite the file column with new values so that the same file becomes like below?

```
123;aaa;10.01.2010
456;bbb;11.01.2015
789;ccc;20.12.2010
222;ddd;15.10.2010
```

Comment: Provide a minimal input and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages sometime.  It is not clear what the 'overwrite' step should do.  Can you provide sample input data (5 lines should be enough), and the desired output?  The `sed` step should be unnecessary (at least to get the correct sorted order — you may need it to get the presentation correct); you can use `-b` to `sort` to ignore leading blanks.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), noting that the input and output are part of the requirements for creating one.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

**Input**

```
$ cat f
123;bbb ;10.01.2010
456;ddd;11.01.2015
789;aaa;20.12.2010
222;ccc;15.10.2010
```

**Using `cut, tr, sort and paste`**

```
$ paste -d ';' <(cut -f 1 -d ';'  f) <(cut -f 2 -d ';'  f | tr -d ' ' | sort) <(cut -f 3 -d ';'  f | sort)
123;aaa;10.01.2010
456;bbb;11.01.2015
789;ccc;15.10.2010 
222;ddd;20.12.2010
```

**Using `cut, tr, sort and pr`**

```
$ pr -mtJs';' <(cut -f 1 -d ';'  f) <(cut -f 2 -d ';'  f | tr -d ' ' | sort) <(cut -f 3 -d ';'  f | sort)
123;aaa;10.01.2010
456;bbb;11.01.2015
789;ccc;15.10.2010
222;ddd;20.12.2010
```

**Using `gawk` (Recommended to use )**

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}FNR==NR{sub(/ +/,"",$2);a[$2];next}FNR==1{asorti(a,b)}{$2=b[FNR]}1' f f
123;aaa;10.01.2010
456;bbb;11.01.2015
789;ccc;20.12.2010
222;ddd;15.10.2010
```

**Explanation (Reading same file twice)**

```
awk  '# START SCRIPT

      BEGIN{
            FS=OFS=";"          # Set input and output field separator
      }  

      # IF the number of records read so far across all files is equal
      # to the number of records read so far in the current file, a
      # condition which can only be true for the first file read, THEN 

      FNR==NR{     
           # Trim space char of field2             
           sub(/ +/,"",$2)

           # populate array "a" such that the value indexed by the field2
           a[$2]

           # Move on to the next record so we do not do any processing intended
           # for records from the second file. 
           next
      }
      # When we read first record of same file read second time then
      FNR==1{
           # asorti() sorts based on keys (or indexes, or indices, hence the "i")
           asorti(a,b)
      }
      {  
         # replace field to value with array value
         $2=b[FNR]

      }1    # }1 at the end does default operation print $0

   ' f f    # input same file twice
```

Comment: With care, it would be possible to write the Awk script so that it does not need to reread the data file, at the cost of storing the whole file in memory.  With a data file as in the question, the repeated scan isn't a problem.  If the input came from a pipe or other non-repeatable source, then the rescan ceases to be an option.  The `cut`'n'`paste`-based solutions also depend on the input being a file so that it can be processed multiple times.  This is very much a minor nit-pick, not a major flaw.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, can be processed in `END` block, but for expected o/p I thought `$2=b[FNR]` would be easy by reading twice